# Paint strokewidth changes to default when selecting other color

Tags: android, refresh, paint

I'm almost done with my app which I make in Eclipse. It is now possible to select stroke width , color en clear screen all in the actionbar.
The problem I have is whenever I click on the actionbar the canvas resets and I lose my painting, this also occurs when I select a different color or stroke size. And when I launch the app I have to click on the actionbar before I can draw.
This is the problem I have.

Also when I choose a different stroke size, the black color stroke size changes correctly but when I change the color afterwards the stroke size resizes to default.

Below is my code. I hope someone is able to help me. Thanks!

**SingleTouchActivity.java**

```
public class SingleTouchActivity extends Activity {

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         SingleTouchEventView stev = new SingleTouchEventView(this, null);
            setContentView(stev);
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.ResetAction) {
                invalidate();
                    return true;
            }if (id == R.id.LijnDun) {
                stev.setStrokeWidth(4);
                    return true;
            }if (id == R.id.LijnDik) {
                stev.setStrokeWidth(5);
                    return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.LijnGroen) {
                stev.setColor(3);
                    return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.LijnBlauw) {
                    stev.setColor(2);
                    return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.LijnRood) {
                       stev.setColor(1);

                       return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void invalidate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

**SingleTouchEventView.Java**

```
public class SingleTouchEventView extends View {
  private Paint paint = new Paint();
  private Path path = new Path();

  public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
      return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
      path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
      break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      // nothing to do
      break;
    default:
      return false;
    }

    // Schedules a repaint.
    invalidate();
    return true;
  }

  // KLEUR  switch statement
  void setColor(int i){

      switch (i){
         case 1:

             paint.setColor(Color.RED);

         break;

         case 2:

             paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

         break;

         case 3:

             paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

         break;

         default:

             paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

         break;  

      }

    }
  // LIJN DIKTE  switch statement
  void setStrokeWidth(int k){

      switch (k){
         case 5:

             paint.setStrokeWidth(12f);

         break;

         case 4:

             paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);

         break;

        default:

             paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);

         break;  

      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In onOptionsItemSelected, you are creating a new instance of your View each time. This will reset all value to default then perform your option button action. You have to perform changes on an existing instance of your view. Make your View singleton.